# Django - response for request AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm using this JQuery autocomplete plugin http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ in my project. I followed this tutorial http://tips4php.net/2010/09/ajax-autocomplete-with-jquery-and-php/.

jQuery code for **Autocomplete**:

```
$('#add-keywords').autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:'/keywords_suggestions',
        minChars:3,
        maxHeight:220,
        width:280,
        zIndex: 9999,
        onSelect: function(value, data){ $('#add-keywords').val(value); },
});
```

The Ajax GET request from JQuery Autocomplete has no problem. It is like, if I type **"developer"** in the `input text` the GET request url would be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?query=developer
```

I'm getting that parameter **query** in Django like this:

```
def kkeywords_suggestions(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
                q = request.GET.get('query', '')
                try:
                        g = KeywordsModel.objects.filter(keyword__startswith=q).order_by('count')
                except KeywordsModel.DoesNotExist:
                        return HttpResponse("not")
                else:
                        for i in range(1,(len(g)+1)):
                                s = []
                                s.append(g[i-1].keyword)
                        to_json = {
                                query: q,
                                suggestions: s,
                                }
                        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Django Models.py:

```
class KeywordsModel(models.Model):
        keyword = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
        count = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
```

The problem occurs from here `request.GET.get('query', '')`. It shows the error

```
ValueError at /keywords_suggestions/
The view information.views.keywords_suggestions didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

**UPDATE-1**

Sorry, the error in Chrome Network tab is like this

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?query=web
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

When I checked in that URL, It shows blank page. Why?

**UPDATE-2**

I removed `request.is_ajax()` from the views. Now I'm getting this error:

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'query' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/nirmal/try/information/views.py in keywords_suggestions, line 123
```

Why django considering `query` as a global name? It is the one I'm trying to fetch from the url.

Could anyone help me to make a perfect **HttpResponse** for that Autocomplete feature?

Thanks!

Comment: umm what happens if the request isn't ajax? if it isn't ajax return something, stating as such. is_ajax works by checking if the request was made using XMLHttpRequest if it wasn't it returns false.

Comment: make all httpresponse as mimetype='application/json')

Comment: I recommend removing the is_ajax part and simply testing the URL on your browser and set DEBUG to True to see what django is doing.

Comment: Also that URL doesn't look right.

Comment: @samy.vilar Debug is already True in my settings. Why the url is not right?

Comment: this => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?query=web` doesn't seem right specially when your previously stated `http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions?query=developer` restart the server it could be in a bad state ...

Comment: `web` and `developer` are the values which I typed in the input text. That doesn't seems to be a problem

Comment: look closer at the url theres a forward slash before the GET parameters.

Comment: @samy.vilar Sorry, I put it wrong. This is the right one `http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?query=developer` Thanks! Please check the updated question.

Comment: I must be tire, for such a problem to escape me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be.

```
to_json = {'query': q, 'suggestions': s}
```

basically what was happening is that `{query:q ...` python was looking for the variable query in order to set the key in the dictionary, to what ever string query may have being pointing to, but no such variable existed and such it returned an error ...

`global name 'query' is not defined` as the error states, python was looking for variable query, it first checks locally in the function scope and then it moves upwards until it hits the global scope if it isn't found it throws that exception.

Comment: I changed it. What is that NameError?

Comment: So how can I fetch that `?query=developer` query value in the Django views. Could u give the correct request.GET code?

Comment: umm what you have there looks correct, you just werent creating the proper dictionary to return. it should work now.

Comment: `request.GET.get('query', '')` is the correct thing to do request.GET is a dictionary when calling .get('query', '') either gets value that the key query is pointing to or returns '' if the key query isn't in the dictionary, you should be good now. you could add the is_ajax back though its up to you if this view is only meant for auto_complete theres no point ...

Comment: No @samy.vilar I'm still getting the same NameError that's why I asked why it didn't consider the `query` as the one from the URL

Comment: huh I take it you updated the dictionary from `to_json = {query: q, suggestions: s}` to `to_json = {'query': q, 'suggestions': s}` whats on line 123 can you copy/paste that line.